# Pipe to egrep in bash script and save to variable

Tags: bash

I am a newby to bash-scripting and have some problems with a bash script I am trying to write. See this code snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                    
year=`date +'%Y'`                                                                                                                                     
holidaysXML=$(curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET \http://www.spiketime.de/feiertagapi/feiertage/$year | xmllint --format -)                                                
echo "$holidaysXML" | egrep "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|>RP<"
```

In this form, what is printed by echo is as expected but when i try to safe the result to a variable end echo the variable it seems the egrep-part is not performed or nothing is performed at all.

After reading some other threads i already tried things like the following:

```
test=$( "$holidaysXML" | egrep "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|>RP<" )
```

or

```
test=`"$holidaysXML" | egrep "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|>RP<"`
```

both not giving the expected result (not the same as in the first code-snippet). Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When writing

```
"$holidaysXML" | egrep ...
```

the value of `$holidaysXML` is interpreted as a command. Most likely, there is no such command on your system, so there is no output which can be sent to `egrep`. To send the value of `$holidaysXML` to `egrep` use either

```
echo "$holidaysXML" | egrep ...
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' "$holidaysXML" | egrep ...
```

or

```
egrep ... <<< "$holidaysXML"
```

The last version is recommended for `bash`. For portable scripts use `printf` (`echo` [behaves](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/187122) [differently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70459/187122) for different shells).

To save the output, put everything in `$(...)`:

```
myVariable="$(egrep ... <<< "$holidaysXML")"
```

Comment: Good answer. As a minor quibble -- `printf '%s\n' "$holidaysXML" | ...` has slightly fewer corner cases than `echo "$holidaysXML" | ...` -- the behavior of `echo` varies between even POSIX-compliant platforms; output is entirely undefined by the standard when any argument contains a backslash literal.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good to know. I'll add the `printf` version, but keep the `echo` so that beginners still get whats going on.

Comment: Now that i see it, it should have been pretty obvious. I feel kind of stupid now. Have my thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is partially correct, i.e.:

```
# This is correct
test=$( echo "$holidaysXML" | egrep "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|>RP<" )

# Attempting to echo test as you have mentioned will strip whitespaces
echo $test
```

What went wrong is that you are probably echoing using `echo $test` instead of `echo "${test"}`. Remember that echoing within double inverted commas will force bash to preserve whitespaces, so this should work:

```
test=$( echo "$holidaysXML" | egrep "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|>RP<" )
echo "$test"
```

Comment: Eh? The OP doesn't have any `echo` in the command they're running inside their command substitutions at all. I *do* agree that if they're not using quotes when trying to echo or emit the stored value that would be a separate bug, but as the question is currently written, it's fairly clear that they aren't generating the correct value in the first place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think OP did mention it: "*[...]when i try to safe [sic] the result to a variable end echo the variable[...]*"

Comment: Sure -- I'm referring to the code they posted: `test=$( "$holidaysXML" | egrep "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|>RP<" )` -- no `echo`.

Comment: @Terry I interpreted your quote as doing `echo $test`

Comment: (Frankly, I first interpreted the problem the same way you did, but then withdrew my comment when I saw Socowi's answer -- I'd read right over the missing `echo`s in the command substitutions and assumed they weren't quoting when trying to emit output).